# How are .Net subscriptions to COM Interop events handled when RuntimeCallableWrapper gets disconnected (and how to deal with missing events)?

Tags: c#, excel, events, vsto, com-interop

I'm currently writing a VSTO addin for Excel (in C#), where I need to maintain a 1:1 relationship between the Name of the WorkBook in Excel and a property in .Net. This is pretty trivial (below is pseudo-code, but very illustrative of what is happening; might have a signature wrong or similar though):

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    public MyClass() {
        var target = this.Name == null ? 
            globals.ThisAddin.Application.ActiveWorkbook : 
            globals.ThisAddin.Application.Workbooks[this.Name];
        target.AfterSave += this.AfterSaveHandler;
        this.Target = target;
    }

    public string Name {get; private set;}

    public Workbook Target {get;private set;}

    private void AfterSaveHandler(Workbook sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.Name = sender.Name;
    }

    // Unsubscribe from events during IDisposable implementation
    // using this.Target or finding via name
}
```

However, being Excel and Interop, I have an issue: from time to time, `Target` gets disconnected from the actual COM object representing the workbook. In other words, the Workbook hasn't been closed, but accessing properties of the object in .Net gives a nice error along the lines of `The target object has become disconnected from its source`.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66ahbe6y%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), when you subscribe to COM events in .Net, you actually subscribe to the events on the `RuntimeCallableWrapper` instance. This implies there's at least a passing chance that if I check the `Name` property of `MyClass`, it won't actually represent the name of the corresponding Workbook instance, because the user may have saved the file under a different name after `Target` disconnected (and consequently `AfterSaveHandler` became unbound from the actual COM object). If I then need to do something with the object to which `MyClass` corresponds in Excel, I can't; the best I can do is attempt to find an object with the last known name, but that could be:

1. The right workbook
2. The wrong workbook (the user saved the original one using SaveAs, then opened a new document with the expected name)
3. No workbook (incorrectly) since the workbook is still open but the name has changed.

Can anyone suggest a solution, or help me understand why this in't a problem in the making?

Comment: They don't get "handled", they'll raise this exception when you try to unsubscribe them.  Crystal ball says that you are using the Marshal.ReleaseComObject() sledgehammer and called it too early.  Or worse, using the disposal pattern and also unsubscribe events in the finalizer.  A corner-case is a worker thread creating a COM object and that thread terminating but that's very hard to get wrong in an add-in scenario.   You need to post the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: I'm actually not, at least not explicitly - in the context of the AddIn, the `Workbook` always has the same lifetime as the `AddIn`, meaning I don't ever release it explicitly. That doesn't mean it isn't being called by some other method internally, of course, with the same effect. Generally access to the `Workbook` instance is taking place on the main thread, although we do use `Task`s on occasion, so I guess if when they terminate they automatically release all COM objects participating in them, that could result in an early RCW release.

Comment: What if you assign the Event (AfterSaveHandler) to this.Target instead of target? EventHandlers are tending to get lost when the garbage collector is cleaning up things that get out of scope. Maybe the garbage collector is handling target, the var, and invalidating the EventHandler with that. Just a wild guess, the out of scope issue is a well known issue but I'm not sure it applies here.